# Ruby on Rails Form input different than what is added to db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

New to rails and I'm trying to write a large form (30+ inputs almost all numbers)

Mostly radio buttons and maybe some sort of increment buttons. Some radio buttons will give a range 5-10min but when submitted these attributes need to submit a normalized standard number 8 for example so that calculations can be performed. How can I have radio buttons or drop downs that show the user one thing but submits something else behind the scenes to postgresql?

Comment: Why don't you make your life easier and use simple_form gem.  It is highly customizable and can be especially useful given your scenario. (https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form)

Comment: @kparek01  I've been working with SimpleForm but I'm not sure how the attributes in the radio button collections work. Specifically this line in the documentation,   <%= f.input :gender, as: :radio_buttons, collection: [['0', 'female'], ['1', 'male']], label_method: :second, value_method: :first %>

Comment: @kparek01 
I'm not sure what the :first and :second refer to, do they store information for the db? Here is a line for radio buttons that I was working on <%= f.collection_radio_buttons :average_shower, prompt: "How long is the average shower in your household?",[[4.0, 'Under 5 min'] ,[8.0, '5-10 min'], [13.0, '10-15 min'] , [15.0, 'Over 15 min']]%>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select with an `options_for_select`. This will allow you to display something that is different from what is sent in the params to the controller

It would be something along the line of:
`<%= f.select :some_attribute, options_for_attribute, {}, prompt: 'Select One' %>`

and then off in your application helper or somewhere:

```
def options_for_attribute
  [
    ['1','8'],
    ['2','9']
  ]
end
```

See:
https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/options_for_select